# Kronecker product SVD

Tags: matrices, svd, kronecker-product

> Suppose $a \in \mathbb R^{n_1n_2n_3}$. Show how to compute $f \in \mathbb R^{n_1}$ and $g \in \mathbb R^{n_2}$ so that $$\| a - h \otimes g \otimes f \|_2$$ is minimized where $h \in \mathbb R^{n_3}$ is given.

Is there a way to solve this question using the SVD?

Comment: Is $\|\cdot \|_2$ the Frobenius norm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using SVD (after vectorizing slices), we can decompose $a$ into a sum of the form
$$
a = \sum_{i=1}^k h_i \otimes m_i
$$
where $h_i \in \Bbb R^{n_3}, m_i \in \Bbb R^{n_1n_2}$, $h_1 = h$, $\|m_i\| = 1$, and $\langle h_i,h_j \rangle = \langle m_i,m_j \rangle = 0$ whenever $i \neq j$.

It follows that
$$
a - h\otimes g \otimes f = 
h \otimes (M_1 - g \otimes f) + 
\sum_{i=2}^k h_i  \otimes m_i.
$$
Now, because all terms in the sum are mutually orthogonal, we have
$$
\begin{align}
\|a - h\otimes g \otimes f\|^2 &= 
\|h \otimes (m_1 - g \otimes f)\|_2^2 + 
\sum_{i=2}^k \|h_i  \otimes m_i\|_2^2
\\ & = \|h\| \cdot \|m_1 - g \otimes f\|_2^2 + 
\sum_{i=2}^k \|h_i\|_2^2.
\end{align}
$$
Thus, it suffices to find $f,g$ so that $\|m_1 - g \otimes f\|_2^2$ is minimized.

This also can be solved using SVD: By unvectorizing, we reframe this as finding $f,g$ such that $\|M_1 - gf^T\|$ is minimized (where $M_1 = \operatorname{vec}^{-1}(m_1)$). By the [E-Y-M theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-rank_approximation#Basic_low-rank_approximation_problem), we can minimize this quantity by taking $g$ and $f$ to be multiples of the left and right singular vectors (respectively) associated with $\sigma_1$ (the largest singular value of $M_1$) such that $\|f\| \cdot \|g\| = \sigma_1$.

---

Regarding the first step: define the vectorization operator $\operatorname{vec}:\Bbb R^{n_3 \times n_1n_2} \to \Bbb R^{n_1n_2n_3}$ to be the unique map satisfying
$$
\operatorname{vec}(hv^T) = h \otimes v
$$
for any $h \in \Bbb R^{n_3}$ and $v \in \Bbb R^{n_1n_2}$.  Now, let $A = \operatorname{vec}^{-1}(a)$.  The singular value decomposition expresses $A$ as a sum
$$
A = \sum_{i=1}^r \sigma_i \hat h_i m_i^T
$$
where $\hat h_i$ is a unit vector in $\Bbb R^{n_3}$ and $m_i$ is a unit vector in $\Bbb R^{n_1n_2}$.  If we define $h_i = \sigma_i h_i$, then we can rewrite this as
$$
A = \sum_{i=1}^r h_i m_i^T.
$$
If we vectorize both sides, then we get
$$
a = \operatorname{vec}(A) = 
\sum_{i=1}^r \operatorname{vec}(h_i m_i^T) = 
\sum_{i=1}^r h_i \otimes m_i.
$$
In order to get the matrix $M_i$ from $m_i$, vectorize with respect to $n_2$ and $n_3$.

Comment: I understood your answer. But, I am confused with the initial part. How were you able to do the SVD decomposition of $a$ like that? Are you using CP approximation?

Comment: How are you assuming column-wise mutual orthogonality?

Comment: The orthogonality of the terms comes immediately from the properties of SVD.

Comment: Before I explain anything, I need to check something: when you say that $a \in \Bbb R^{n_1n_2n_3}$, do you mean that $a$ is a vector of length $n_1n_2n_3$, or are you saying that $a$ is a rank-3 tensor?

Comment: $a \in \mathbb{R}^{n_1n_2n_3}$ is a vector of length $n_1n_2n_3$

Comment: All right.  When I find time, I'll explain the procedure accordingly

Comment: I've added a detailed explanation of the first step, but as of now the results are inconsistent.  Really, there is another vectorization operator with respect to $n_2$ and $n_3$ that takes us from $M_i$ to $m_i$.

Comment: I've fixed the explanation now; everything is consistent.  See my latest edit.